# How to use useEffect() to fetch data from an api in a useReducer() and useContext() state management setup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

`reducer.js`

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_HEROES:
      return { ...state, heroes: action.heroes }
  }
}
```

`AppContext.js`

```
export const AppContext = React.createContext()

export const AppProvider = (props) => {
  const initialState = { 
    heroes: [] 
  }

  const [appState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  const setHeroes = async () => {
    const result = await getHeroes()
    dispatch({ type: SET_HEROES, heroes: result })
  }

  return <AppContext.Provider
    values={{ heroes: appState.heroes, setHeroes }}
  >
    {props.children}
  </AppContext.Provider>
}
```

`HeroesScreen.js`

```
const HeroesScreen = () => {
  const { heroes, setHeroes } = useContext(AppContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeroes()
  }, [])

  return <>
  // iterate hero list
  </>
}

export default HeroesScreen
```

Above is plain simple setup of a component using reducer + context as state management. Heroes are showing on the screen, everything works fine but I'm having a warning `Reach Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setHeroes'`. But if I add it in as a dependency, it'll crash my app with `Maximum depth update exceeded`

Been searching but all I see is putting the function fetch call inside the `useEffect()`. What I would like is to extract the function and put it in a separate file following the SRP principle

EDITED:

As advised on using `useCallback()`

`AppContext.js`

```
const setHeroes = useCallback(() => {
    getHeroes().then(result => dispatch({ type: SET_HEROES, heroes: result }))
  }, [dispatch, getHeroes])
```

`HeroesScreen.js`

```
useEffect(() => {
  setHeroes()
}, [setHeroes])
```

Adding the `getHeroes` as dependency on `useCallback`, linter shows unnecessary dependency

Comment: You could 'useCallback' your setHeroes func so it won't get created over and over, while keeping `setHeroes` in useEffect deps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code in `AppProvider`, you are creating a new `setHeroes` function every time it renders. So if you add `setHeroes` as a dependency to `useEffect` the code executes something like this:

1. `AppProvider` renders, `setHeroes` is created, the state is initial state
2. Somewhere down the component hierarchy `HeroesScreen` renders. `useEffect` is called which in turn calls `setHeroes`
3. `getHeroes` is called and an action is dispatched
4. reducer changes the state which causes `AppProvider` to re-render
5. `AppProvider` renders, `setHeroes` is created from scratch
6. The `useEffect` executes again since `setHeroes` changed and the whole loop repeats forever!

To fix the issue you indeed need to add `setHeroes` as a dependency to `useEffect` but then wrap it using `useCallback`:

```
const setHeroes = useCallback(async () => {
  const result = await getHeroes();
  dispatch({ type: SET_HEROES, heroes: result });
}, [getHeroes, dispatch]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made progress now. However, linter now shows `React Hook useCallback has an unnecessary dependecy: getHeroes`, should we remove the dependency or is there some steps to remove this warning?

Comment: There is an open issue with `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` exhaustive-deps lint rule that seems to match your case https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18051 If you want a workaround you can try removing the `async` / `await` and using `getHeroes` the old school way, `.then` :)

Comment: If I use the old school way. I don't need to add `getHeroes` as dependency? `useCallback(() => { getHeroes().then(result => dispatch))}, [dispatch])`

Comment: No I mean the old way will not break your linter, the error that you are seeing is caused by (most probably) linter not recognising that you are using `getHeroes` because of the `async` / `await`. But that's only my guess based on the bug report above. You should still add it to the list of dependencies!

Comment: I've removed async/await keyword and used the old `.then()` method. Still having the warning on linter. Please see edited post.

Comment: In that case I would either disable the lint rule until the bug I sent is fixed :/

Answer (score 2):

Good question, I also had this problem, this is my solution. I'm using Typescript but it'll work with JS only as well.

`UserProvider.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'
import UserContext from './UserContext'
import { getUser } from './actions/profile'
import userReducer, { SET_USER } from './UserReducer'

export default ({ children }: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, {})

  const getUserData = async () => {
    const { user } = await getUser()
    dispatch({ type: SET_USER, payload: { ...user } })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user: state }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Then wrap your App with the provider

`index.tsx`

```
<UserProvider>
  <App />
</UserProvider>
```

Then to use the Context Consumer I do this

`AnyComponent.tsx`

```
<UserConsumer>
   {({ user }) => {
     ...
   }} 
</UserConsumer
```

or you can also use it like this

```
const { user } = useContext(UserContext)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Should we put `getUserData` as a dependency on `useEffect()`?

Comment: @BoyPasmo no need, `getUserData` is a constant function so adding it as dependency on `useEffect()` will not make a difference. Also, `useEffect()` will be executed once when the application loads and this will get the user data then. After that you will have the user throughout your whole app.

Comment: Got it. But how would you, say, fetch data (getHeroes) using an api with `useEffect()` in a page? I'm struggling with its dependency. An example would be great

Comment: How it works is that if you add dependency in the `useEffect()` then the `useEffect()` will load every time that dependency change its value. 

How to call an API in useEffect is the same as the example that I have posted above

`const apiCall = async () => {
   const data = await get('/some_api')
   setState(data)
}

useEffect(()=> {
   apiCall()
},[])
`
notice if the dependencies is [] empty array this will be only executed once, or else the api call will be triggered every time the value in the dependency changes

Comment: I've edited my post. Can you check please? See if I did something wrong or not advisable

Comment: You need to call this function `useEffect(() => { setHeroes() }, [])` in the `AppProvider`, not in the `HeroesScreen.js`. In the `HeroesScreen.js` you will have the `AppContext.Consumer` like I put in the example above and then the consumer will return you back the `heroes data`. Check my `index.tsx` on how to wrap your main `App` file with the Context and then check the `AnyComponent.tsx` to see how to use the consumer.

Comment: I see. In that case, say I have more api calls such as `getItems`, `getSkills` and put all of them in `AppProvider`. It'll be pre-loaded even though I don't need them at the moment? Let me know if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Yes, all data will be preloaded, which is not recommended. That's why you should not load everything at once. For me I only need to user info in the global context, after that for each page I will add `useEffect()` if I need to fetch some data for that specific page. Also, keep in mind, you can have multiple `useEffect()` functions in a single component, all of them will be executed when the component mounts, but the ones that have dependency will be triggered every time the dependency value changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214791/discussion-between-boy-pasmo-and-slobodan-jovanovski).